# Эквиваленты ли следующие операторы?

Tags: c#, строки

Допустим у меня есть инициализированная строка `string s`.
Являются ли следующие операторы эквивалентными в плане поведения? Генерируется ли разный IL мне не важно.

```
// 1
s = s + "";

// 2
s = s ?? "";

// 3
s = $"{s}";
```

Если в каких-либо случаях есть отличия, то, пожалуйста, укажите их.

Comment: _Допустим у меня есть инициализированная строка string s_ - как инициализирована? чем?

Comment: @Grundy Хочу все случаи рассмотреть. Она может параметром функции или вводиться пользователем.

Comment: Вариант 2, при прочих равных, лучше, т.к. не создает лишнюю строку. и вся работа сводится к одному сравнению и одному присваиванию ссылки, вместо конкатенации со всеми вытекающими. Если есть возможность не генерировать лишние объекты, лучше их не генерировать, GC только спасибо скажет =)

Comment: Если компилятор достаточно умный. я не в курсе, не проверял, то он сам может заменить 1 и 3 на 2, но это возможно не при любых условиях, поэтому рассчитывать на это не стоит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, все три выражения дают один и тот же результат при одинаковых параметрах.

Различие могло быть только в обработке значения `null`, но во всех трех выражениях `null` будет заменен - пустой строкой.

Answer (score 1):

> Являются ли следующие операторы эквивалентными в плане поведения?

Это как спрашивать: Являются ли следующие действия одинаковыми:

4+2+2

4*2

6+2

**Нет. Действия разные. Хотя результат одинаковый.**

Так что: Нет. Операторы разные и действия разные соответственно. Конкретно в даном случае РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ будут эквивалентны. **Результаты. Но не операторы.** :)

Поведение, собственно тоже будет немного отличатся. Вполне возможно что некоторые из этих вариантов будет немного быстрее (хотя они все быстрые). Но существенной разницы ты вряд ли получишь, даже, на детализированных тестах.